# Optaplanner model for pattern matching

Tags: optaplanner

I'm new to optaplanner and am trying to figure out how to model my domain.

There is a set of Things, which each have a type and a set of properties (e.g., Map<String,String>).

There is also a set of ThingPatterns, which also have a type and a set of of properties, except the value of a property may be a constant or a variable. The same variable may appear in multiple properties across multiple ThingPatterns.

The problem is to assign Things to ThingPatterns such that the types match and that all properties on an ThingPattern are present on the assigned Thing. (That is, the ThingPattern describes the kind of Thing being looked for.).

If an ThingPattern's property's value is a variable, then it can match to any value of a property with the same name, but all such variable bindings need to be the same across all properties across all ThingPatterns where that variable appears.

Example:

```
Thing1
   type A
   properties
      a = b
      c = d
Thing2
   type B
   properties
      x = y
      z = d
ThingPattern1
   type A
   properties
      a = b
      c = <v> // <v> is a variable
ThingPattern2
   type B
   properties
      z = <v> // <v> is a variable
```

In this example `Thing1` would bind to `ThingPattern1`, `Thing2` would bind to `ThingPattern2`, and `<v>` would have the value `d`.

In general, there may be a lot of things and patterns, and a complete assignment may not be possible (in many cases it's overconstrained).

I started to put it together like this:

```java
class Thing {
    String type;
    Map<String, String> properties;
}

@PlanningEntity
class ThingPattern {
    String type;
    Map<String, String> properties; // where a variable is a special kind of string, like surrounded by <>?
    @PlanningVariable
    Thing thing;
}

class Solution {
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    Set<Thing> things;
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    Set<ThingPattern> thingPatterns;
    @PlanningScore
    HardSoftScore score;
```

But I haven't figured out how to enforce that all places a variable appears will have the same value bound to it. I thought about breaking out properties and variables into their own classes, but then it seems like I'd have multiple `@PlanningEntity` without an obvious way to chain them.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't grok this. Can you give an example of Thing and ThingPattern? My first thought, for your current model, is you just need a ConstraintStream to `.filter()` on a `compatible(Thing, ThingPattern)` boolean method - and this works in both OptaPlanner and [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/) - but obviously if property c and z are also planning variables, your current model is irrelevant. So I need more context to understand what/how you're trying to plan.

Comment: In the example given, ThingPattern1 is saying, "Find me a Thing that has type "A", a property "a" with value "b", and a property "c" with a value bound to variable "<d>". Then ThingPattern2 is saying "Find me a Thing that has type "B", a property "x" with value "y", and a property "z" with a value also bound to variable "<d>". So, "<d>" can have any value as long as it's the same in both Things that get matched to these patterns.

I am also considering doing this via a ConstraintStream, but wasn't sure if that was the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up handling it via constraints. Basically, I have two constraints, one to check for variable binding conflicts within a single `ThingPattern`, and one to check for variable binding conflicts across pairs of `ThingPattern`s. In both cases, the constraints look for properties that are variables in a `ThingPattern` and then if two different property values have the same variable, it checks the actual value (the "binding") in the attached `Thing`s to see if they are the same or not.